# What are TypeScript locals?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out what TypeScript locals are, or in other words, what the `noUnusedLocals` setting in the `tsconfig.json` is for. On the [TypeScript compiler options page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) this setting is described as `Report errors on unused locals.`, but this does not really help me understanding.

Could someone please explain this to a mortal like me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things from the current file. Like imports, vars, functions, etc. that are private to the current file and not used anywhere.

Comment: Ok, so if I compile/transpile to JavaScript I get notified about imports, vars, functions that are "just laying around" unused? Is this a warning or an error?

Comment: It will be an error. Similar to `error TS6133: 'test' is declared but its value is never read.`